# How to produce answer key in exam class for the fill in the blanks questions along with multiple choice questions?

Tags: fill

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Sample Question 1
    \begin{choices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \choice Option3
    \correctchoice Option4
    \end{choices}
\question Sample Question 2
    \begin{choices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \correctchoice Option3
    \choice Option4
    \end{choices}
\question Fill in the \fillin{blanks} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The problem is to produce answerkey at the end of all questions in the format:

1. Ans:(D)
2. Ans:(C)
3. blanks